# R: rbind matrices and create indicator variable

Tags: r

I have set of 30 matrices called `index.1` to `index.30` in a list `listname`. I can combine them into a single matrix using `do.call`:

```
new.matrix = do.call(rbind, listname)
```

But how can I create a variable in the matrix as an indicator to show which matrix each observation came from originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat1<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)
mat2<-matrix(c(13,3,0,0),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)
mat1
mat2
matindex<-c(rep(1,length(mat1[,1])),rep(2,length(mat2[,1])))
listname<-list(mat1,mat2)
new.matrix <- do.call(rbind, listname)
finalnewmatrix<-cbind(new.matrix,matindex)
finalnewmatrix
# or if you want the index as rownames then...
# rownames(new.matrix)<-matindex
```

To automate this more and save typing for many matrices you can do:

```
lengths  <- sapply(listname, nrow)
matindex <- rep(seq_along(listname), lengths)
new.matrix <- do.call(rbind, listname)
finalnewmatrix <- cbind(new.matrix, matindex)
```

Comment: @flodel ha `seq_along` is indeed more automated. `nrow` does look cleaner but out of curiosity do we derive any benefits over the anonymous function with `length`?

Comment: `nrow` is probably faster than your `function(x)length(x[,1])`; also more robust, e.g. with `matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=0)`.

Comment: You can have both: `NROW` calls `length` if the object does not have dimensions, otherwise it returns `dim(x)[1L]` (i.e. `nrow(x)`)